# A conceptual question about maximum diode reverse voltage

Tags: diodes, datasheet

To illustrate my question I will use an example scenario to make it clear. Imagine you have a diode where its datasheet shows maximum diode reverse voltage as 5 V, imagine it is wired as follows:

[image]

My question is: Is just saying reverse voltage is 5 V sufficient? It is because imagine R1 is air and from common sense I can say that the diode will not be damaged. And imagine that R1 is variable and we start lowering it from air resistance down to 50 Ω.

So in that case, as we lower the value of R1 there must be a point where the diode starts to get damaged. But what R1 value is that? I'm a bit confused with interpreting maximum reverse voltage.

*Important information from comment:*

Here is one example with low max reverse voltage 2 V: [datasheet](https://eblanaphotonics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/EP1950-DM-B.pdf) So from datasheet of this there is no info about leakage current. As an example: With total 100 Ω in series to the diode would applying 5 V reverse voltage damage this laser? How to make estimate in such case

Comment: Do not understand what baffles you: the current is defined by both the diode I-V curve and the R1 resistance, and the voltage across D1 is defined by the current and the diode I-V curve. So you solve the equations and find the voltage across D1. If it is greater than 5V, the diode can be damaged, if smaller, the probability of damage is low and sharply diminishes with this voltage decreasing below the datasheet maximum diode reverse voltage. Or is it asked just for fun?

Comment: @V.V.T Do not understand what buffles you. You wrote a whole answer into the comment section, an answer that perfectly covers OPs question.

Comment: @pipe If you agree with my comment (except for the baffling part), you can just upvote it

Comment: Do you have a specific example diode? A LED or silicon diode or schottky, maybe Zener or TVS diode? Rectifier or small-signal? Reverse voltage may mean different things for different purposes so please be clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

So you are talking about laser diodes.

They are extremely senstive devices, even more sensitive than LEDs.

Please note that for your laser, the maximum reverse voltage is under absolute maximum ratings.

The normal usage for laser diodes is to only use them under forward bias, or zero bias when turned off.

Which means that under normal operation, there should never be any negative voltage over it.

So the absolute maximum rating is already very far from normal operating conditions, so the diode of course can't operate normally outside normal operating conditions.

The absolute maximum rating just means damage will happen after this voltage. Of course what the datasheet does not say is the current for the reverse voltage, but that's not important, as why would you ever apply negative voltage intentionally, or even design a circuit where a negative bias is possible, or intentionally allow up to 2V negative bias.

So because the current is irrelevant, it just meas that you should never apply more than 2V negative bias, not even through a current limit resistor.

The current may be so small that virtually no current passes through the diode even at 5V negative bias and 1 megaohm resistor, but you still exceeded the -2V limit.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about a real diode, you need to consider the reverse leakage current of the diode. Let‘s assume this is 1uA. So if you have very high resistance like 1 Meg Ohms, then 1V will be dropped at your resistor and the diode only gets 4V instead of 5V. In any case, if the diode max rating is 5V, it will not get damaged in your circuit with 5V source voltage.

Comment: Is 1uA a good guess for any diode?

Comment: @user1245 No, but you should maybe add an example of a specific diode to answer your question.

Comment: @Justme Here is one example with low max reverse voltage 2V: https://eblanaphotonics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/EP1950-DM-B.pdf So from datasheet of this there is no info about leakage current. As an example: With total 100 Ohm in series to the diode would applying 5V reverse voltage damage this laser? How to make estimate in such case.

Comment: This is a bad example for „any diode“ because it is very special and the manufacturer did not specify the reverse leakage current, indeed. Yes 5V would damage it, because it is 2V rated.

Comment: @user1245 1 μA might be an okay guess for a Schottky diode (which are particularly leaky) under particularly bad conditions (high temperature), but not in general.